# Organizing several long Switches

Tags: c++, switch-statement

This might come down to opinion but I don't know and that's why I'm asking.

I'm going to have several long switch statements in one method. (I have multiple instances of switching a Uint8 from 0x3F -> 0x00 and assume I can't necessarily exchange the variables used in the cases) This is going to make the method very long and difficult to navigate. What are some effective ways to make the code more navigable? My initial thought is to make multiple separate methods for each but I don't know how that effects the cycles or build times.

Here's a truncated example of the code that will appear with several variations but with different case effects that need to be separated:

```
    switch (surroundingTiles) {
                                //Using Sprite 30
                            case 0x09:
                                renderer->render(xPos, yPos, renderable->getRenderable(), &m_sprite[30], viewPort, 120, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
                                break;
                            case 0x12:
                                renderer->render(xPos, yPos, renderable->getRenderable(), &m_sprite[30], viewPort, 0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
                                break;
                            case 0x24:
                                renderer->render(xPos, yPos, renderable->getRenderable(), &m_sprite[30], viewPort, 60, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
                                break;
***
***
***
                    //using sprite 41
                    case 0x3F:
                        renderer->render(xPos, yPos, renderable->getRenderable(), &m_sprite[41], viewPort, 0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
                        break;

                    //throw error sprite
                    default:
                        renderer->render(xPos, yPos, renderable->getRenderable(), &m_sprite[6], viewPort, 0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
                        break;
```

Here's a quick pseudo for what I'm thinking of:

```
switchMethod1();
//some code
switchMethod2();
```

Where each of those methods contains a lengthy switch statement.

Comment: can you give some example? (both original and what you propose)

Comment: How much code actually differs between each case? If it's as little as shown in your question, is there some reason you cannot use a lookup table for the few parameters that differ?

Comment: I've never used a look up table before so I didn't really know to apply it here. I'll start reading up on that. For the sake of argument though, lets assume I can't use a look up table, if that's even a possibility.

Comment: Is `(*renderer)` a typo? All other places it's just `renderer`

Comment: I would use a lookup tale for this. It seems the only differences are an array index and whatever 120,0,and 60 are.

Comment: Yeah, `(*renderer)` is a typo, I'll go fix that.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have shown:
What's changing between `//Using Sprite 30` block and `//Using Sprite 41` block is the index of the `m_sprite` array.
And within `//Using Sprite 30` block, the change happens with the parameter that follows `viewport`. Lets call it `seaPort`.

So lookup table seems to be a good option here:

```
static const Uint8 SeaPortLookUp[256] = {120, 0, 60, .... 60, 0, 120};
static const Uint8 SpriteLookUp[256] = {30, 41, 6, .... 6, 30, 41};
```

Then the switch statement can be rewritten as:

```
spriteIndex = SpriteLookUp[surroundingTiles]; 
seaPort = SeaPortLookUp[surroundingTiles]; 
renderer->render(xPos, yPos, renderable->getRenderable(), &m_sprite[spriteIndex], viewPort, seaPort, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two style-suggestions:

First, do everything you can to minimize the number of times you repeat the same characters over and over again.

For example, in your posted code, it looks like all (or most) of your cases look like this:

```
renderer->render(xPos, yPos, renderable->getRenderable(), &m_sprite[30], viewPort, 120, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
```

... with a little variable-renaming, and/or declaring a few local variables at the top of your switch-statement, you could get it down to this instead:

```
r->render(x, y, r2, &ms[30], vp, 120, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
```

The reason for keeping things as brief as possible is simple:  the less text there is to type, the less text there is to read and debug, and therefore the easier it is to verify and maintain the table.

(You could probably go even further by employing inline-helper-functions and/or macros, but there is a point of diminishing returns where brevity turns into obscurity)

My second suggestion is that if your code is acting as a big table/spreadsheet, then you can format it to look like a big table/spreadsheet.

For example, instead of this:

```
switch (surroundingTiles) {
  case 0x09:
     r->render(x, y, r2, &ms[30], vp, 120, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
  break;
  case 0x12:
     r->render(x, y, r2, &ms[25], vp, 32, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
  break;
  case 0x24:
     r->render(x, y, r2, &ms[2], vp, 1, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
  break;
  [...]
```

.... make it look more like this, if you can:

```
switch (surroundingTiles) {
   case 0x09: r->render(x, y, r2, &ms[30], vp, 120, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE); break;
   case 0x12: r->render(x, y, r2, &ms[25], vp,  32, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE); break;
   case 0x24: r->render(x, y, r2, &ms[2],  vp,   1, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE); break;
   [...]
```

The reason for doing it this way is that if you can line the columns up above each other, then it becomes really easy for the eye to scan up and down each column for errors and typos -- anything "out of the ordinary" for a given column will be much easier to spot if you don't have to separately scan left and right to locate where the column starts for each line.  (Of course it's possible to overdo this and end up with lines that are so long they can't be viewed except on very wide monitors)

```
switchMethod1();
//some code
switchMethod2();
```

Decomposing a big function into several smaller functions is never a bad idea, especially if each smaller function has a separate and easily-describable purpose.  (i.e. if it's easy to come up with an intuitive/self-describing name for the function, then you're on the right track)  Switch/case statements can't always be easily split apart that way, though (i.e. sometimes you might want to execute only `switchMethod1()` and not `switchMethod2()` instead of always executing both of them)